# How to add custom XML storage part to Word doc - preferrably with docx4j

Tags: java, ms-word, openxml, docx, docx4j

I'm trying to populate a Word content control with XML data using docx4j (version 3.2.1). I'm evaluating this in order to use it for invoice generation. The documents we want to generate are not very complicated so this looks like a good approach to me.

I have created the content control through Word 2010 dev tools. This is how I try to inject the XML into the docx (taken from [this example](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlsMergeXML.java)):

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));

FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));

Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML & Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML);
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Couldn't find CustomXmlDataStoragePart! exiting..
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.bind(Docx4J.java:300)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.bind(Docx4J.java:271)
```

**How can I add the CustomXmlDataStoragePart with docx4j, if it doesn't exist yet? Or should/can I do this in Word directly?**

Note: I decided to prepare templates in Word directly, because later on these templates must be edited by non-technical users and I don't want to burden them with extra tools, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you "created the content control through Word 2010 dev tools".  Unless you mean the content control toolkit, you need to use that or better, either of the OpenDoPE Word addins.  Not both.

These tools add a custom xml part into the docx, and allow you to associate it with your content controls via XPath data bindings.

Then, when at runtime you invoke Docx4J.bind, docx4j finds that existing custom xml part, and replaces it with the xml file you provide which contains your runtime data.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this thread like I have. This update might help as lots of things have matured since these 2010 tools mentioned in the original response.

Since around version 16 of Word, it’s been easier to do customXML xpath bindings directly in Word when making templates. This is done in developer tab with XML Mapping side pane open. You just load in your custom xml by clicking the drop down and adding a new xml part. Your XML structure will appear and you can directly add elements as content controls to your document by right clicking and adding the relevant control type, or you can add the controls first and use the mapping panel to bind the xml element to the control.

That’s usually good enough as a start, and to tweak it’s not that difficult in ooxml to add/edit bindings manually in the places where content controls occur in a document. For example if you add all the content controls you need in word and save the file as a docx, you can open it as a zip archive and open the header/footer/document xml. Then perform a search for <w:sdtPr> which is the start tag for a content control’s properties.
An optional child of this is    <w:dataBinding w:prefixMappings="xmlns:ns0='http://example'" w:xpath="/ns0:root/name/first" />.

If your customXML doesn’t need namespaces, you wouldn’t need the prefiMappings attribute. See [learn.microsoft.com databinding documentation for more specific details on its attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.databinding?view=openxml-3.0.1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).